# Python Reading An Easy Captcha Tesseract

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, captcha, tesseract

I'm new to captcha decoding and I'm now trying to decode this.

[image: This]

I know, this is easy. But I can't make it.
I have come this far.
[image: This]

But still tesseract can't read this.
The output is 6385145(Yes,pretty close but this is the best result of 20 tries).
The script I'm using so far is.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageEnhance
import urllib,os,pdb
im1 = Image.open("code.png")
im1.save("orjinal.png","PNG")
width, height = im1.size
im2 = im1.crop((0, 0, width, height-11))
im2 = im2.resize((int(width*3), int(height*3)), Image.BICUBIC)
im2.save("code.png")
img = Image.open('code.png')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()
yo = img.getpixel((1,1))
newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == yo[0] and item[1] == yo[1] and item[2] == yo[2]:
        newData.append((0, 0, 0, 255))
    else:
        newData.append(item)
img.putdata(newData)
img.save("captcha.png", "PNG")
os.remove("code.png")
os.system("tesseract -psm 8 captcha.png hi")
with open("hi.txt") as f:
    print f.read()
```

I couldn't delete that white line so I cropped the image.

Other images/results:

[image: 5390?()]

Result: 5390?()

[image]

Result: 16009?

Comment: Tesseract is not the problem here, you have to perform image processing. I't not as simple as you think. If the white line is always in the same place then you ca ntrain tesseract

Comment: How? It is always at the same place.

Comment: same font ? 6 caracteres in length ?

Comment: Yes, same font, always white, the line under them is at the same pixel(11th line from bottom) 6 characters lenght, only background color is diffrent but I already did that.

Comment: so slice the captcha, add a dot at the middle bottom, and tesseract each slice (option 1 caracter in tessesarct )

Comment: 6 crops, you'll have to test  4 and 1

Comment: Well, I will try it. But I didn't understand what you mean at "add a dot at middle bottom"

Comment: to improve OCr you could add a dot to complete caracters like o D d etc.